# Unity: How to import a SINGLE animation for an existing character?

Tags: unity, animation, blender

The Holy Grail of animation solutions (for me). Right now, if I want to append a new animation for an existing character, I don't immediately know what to do. I **assume** I need to bring the same FBX into the Assets folder with the new animation, copy the animation, drag that onto my previous prefab, and delete the new FBX.  But that is such a pain!

I already have a VERY complicated animation tree that is executed via a script and some animation events. How can I quickly save and import a new animation into Unity, made with Blender?

Comment: If you save your updated animations in your original FBX file, do the new additions not appear when Unity automatically re-imports the modified file?

Comment: I have been updating the .blend file because I have more control that way, and exporting a new .fbx each time I change something. I could stash the .fbx from before and overwrite it, but actually, I'm having A LOT of trouble right now exporting my .fbx to Unity...my character's animations to do not play back and he is on his back (sideways) when I upload. So I need to figure out what I'm doing differently for Unity2019.3.13, or what's changed about exporting .fbx from Blender since January. I am working on this, don't worry